# Excel CountIFs with 2 different conditions

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I need to count with the following conditions:

- dates (Range: Incidents!C2:C300) > 1/1/2012
- Categories(Range: Q2:Q300) matches Sheet2!B2:B8

Currently, I have the following formula and is working:

```
=Countifs(Incidents!Q2:Q300,Sheets2!B2:B8)
```

This formula simply count the number of records that are, for example, related to logins

However, when I do

```
=Countifs(Incidents!Q2:Q300,Sheets2!B2:B8, Incidents!C2:C300, ">1/1/2012")
```

I got a **#VALUE** error on my cells

How can I do this ? I need to filter out records that are before 2012.

**Update:**

Data type on Incidents!Q2:Q300: Text
Data type on Sheets2!B2:B8: Text
Data type on Incidents!C2:C300: custom, "dd-mmm-yy h:hh:hh"

Below is the actual code I used that got me the #VALUE error

```
=COUNTIFS(Incidents!$Q$2:$Q$300,Sheet2!B5,Incidents!C2:C300,">1/1/2012")
```

Comment: I tried this myself, but I didn't get any error?  Although I did have to use ctrl+shift+enter to create it as an array formula, because your using a range under the `criteria` field.  By any chance might it be cause your referencing `Sheets2!` rather than `Sheet2!`?

Comment: That first formula actually returns an "array" of results, one for each cell in Sheets2!B2:B8. The result you see can change depending on where you put the formula. How are you using it, is that a single formula or copied down a range, if so what range?

Comment: There's nothing intrinsically wrong with that second formula, when I test it on blank sheets I just get zero.....I don't see how you get #VALUE! error, are there any #VALUE! errors in the referenced ranges?

Comment: @barryhoudini I added an update on my question. I may have described the issue wrongly too. basically, I need to count the number of records on incidents sheet that meets 1)the category specified on B5 and 2)it has to be >1/1/2012 . Sounds logical to me if I am to code in VBA or other language.

Comment: The updated formula syntax is fine...and COUNTIFS normally copes well with errors in the referenced ranges.....so there isn't much that can cause #VALUE! error here - are the sheet names valid as per Skytunnel's comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my mistake. The formula I have does work. The reason it was not working for me was because my range was different on Q and C. On my original formula, I have Q2:Q300 and C2:C355.  As such, I encountered a #VALUE error. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error for **2 out of 11** worksheets using the following formula: `=COUNTIF('[worksheet name]'!O:O,"Pre")`, which was perfectly valid, and worked fine for the other nine worksheets.

I could only get them to work by copying the entire contents of the failing worksheets into new worksheets, deleting the old ones and renaming the new.  I had to copy the same worksheet names back into the formulae, which then worked, even though nothing had actually changed!